# Using Ansible, how does one temporarily shut down a GCP VM instance, as opposed to deleting it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

Using the gcp_compute_instance command in ansible, how does one achieve the same as 'shut down' on the GCP console?

Comment: One option is to send the 'shutdown now' command, preceded by safely shutting down services:

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Zeitounator

status: TERMINATED does indeed work, but then one must be sure to set the deletion_protection parameter, else it complains, fatally.

```
   - name: Shut down a GCP instance temporarily
      gcp_compute_instance:
        name: "{{ inventory_hostname_short }}"
        deletion_protection: no
        machine_type: "{{ gcp_ce_machine_type }}"
        disks:
          - auto_delete: 'false'
            boot: 'true'
            source: "{{ disk }}"
        network_interfaces:
        - network:
          access_configs:
          - name: External NAT
            nat_ip:
            type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
        zone: "{{ gcp_ce_zone }}"
        project: "{{ gcp_ce_project_name }}"
        auth_kind: serviceaccount
        service_account_file: "{{ gcp_ce_service_account_keyfile }}"
        status: TERMINATED
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

One could send a 'shutdown now' command after safely shutting down the database and other services that might not like a hard shut down:

```
- name: Send shutdown now command vi ssh
  command: /usr/bin/ssh "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"@"{{ host-ip-address }}" -C "sudo shutdown now"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: doesnt [`status: TERMINATED`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gcp_compute_instance_module.html#parameter-status) do the job ?

Comment: I cannot seem to find a working example of using status

Comment: If I take for granted the documentation is accurate, you should just have to add `status: TERMINATED` to your actual task creating the instance, and `status: RUNNING` when you want to start it again.Unfortunately, I do not have a GCP account to test against.